# Using Gmail to send an email using MailKit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, gmail, mailkit

TL;DR: Need to 'link' a Gmail account with a .net core web app so that the Gmail account can send emails to users registered on the .net core app on behalf the .net core app via MailKit.

Here is the scenario:

Having a hypothetical gmail account 'bob@gmail.com' with a password '12345', I set up SMTP settings for the account using MailKit in a .net core web application.

Now, within the .net core app, users are registered having t a local username and password eg sarah@somedomain.com.

What I am trying to implement is the functionality that will allow Sarah to reset her password if forgotten. On the login page of the .net core app is a 'Forgot Password' link. The linked page requests a username/email address from the user who forgot their password. Sarah can enter her email address and hit 'Submit' on the form.

The application must then, using the SMTP settings provided to Mailkit, authenticate with the gmail account for bob@gmail.com and send an email to sarah@somedomain.com an email with a reset link.

This is all pretty standard and commonly used, but here is where the problem comes in.

Google has strengthened security arround allowing 'Less Secure Apps'. Enabling 'Less Secure Apps' on bob@gmail.com works, but on occation the 'Less Secure Apps' setting is turned off automatically, prompting an email being sent to bob@gmail.com stating that a login attempt was blocked. Enabling 'Less Secure Apps' again resolves this, bit that is not what I want.

This all worked fine before Google changed their security.

The 'suggested' way to fix this is by using 'App Passwords' with the gmail account, but the question is, how to use the app password within c# and MailKit?

I have contacted Google Support, but they don't get what I am trying. They suggested that when the 'Reset Password' form is submitted, bob@gmail.com must be verified before logging in and sending the reset link mail, which is silly because Sarah has no idea what Bob's password is, not does any othe user who needs to reset their password.

Any alternate solutions are welcome, heck if it is possible to host a simple SMTP server within the .net core app, I'll take it. However, I do not want users to 'Sign in with Google' or Facebook or whatever.

'Solutions' I found online are either outdated or all about presenting the user to 'Sign in with Google' or have the user 'verify' the Google account, but it's not their Google account in question here.

Comment: Have you read about google OAuth 2.0, use this instead of Enabling Less Secure Apps, https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that is exacly what I dont want to do. There should be no interaction required from the user as the account that needs to be accessed is not their account but rather a 'system' account. After Sarah completes the reset password form, she should get an email from bob@gmail.com with a reset link

Comment: Using an App Password is the same as using a regular password. I suspect that if your "Enable Less Secure Apps" checkbox is randomly getting unchecked, app passwords would also stop working, but who knows. I don't know why people insist on using Gmail for these kinds of services, it is the worst possible choice because of the difficulty they make authentication. Use another SMTP server.

Comment: Yes, I am seriously concidering an alternative to Gmail. Only reason I went with it was because I didnt want to use yet ANOTHER service over what I already have. Considering that Google has so many other APIs that you can use by supplying a secret key, it's quite frustrating that you cannot access the SMTP service in a similar way. I mean really, I just want to let my system send an email, nothing fancy